# Activation Object in JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to figure out how closures are implemented in JS (in theory), and there's one thing that confuses me and I couldn't find an answer to.

Closures in JS use a chain of Activation Objects. Each function invocation has one, and it points to its parent's Activation Object, which points to *its* parent's Activation Object and so on.

If I understand correctly, the "parent" in this case is the function call in which the child function was *defined* in.

But how does the child know its parent's Activation Object? The child function could have been called anywhere in the program, even outside of the function call that defined it. Is the Activation Object of the parent somehow stored in the function object itself when the function is defined? Does every function invocation somehow get its parent's Activation Object from its own function object? That's the only explanation I could think of, but I couldn't verify it.

Also, is there a way to inspect an Activation Object (much like how `__proto__` can be inspected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least by ECMA's terms, what you're describing is defined as a [Lexical Environment](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-10.2).

> *A Lexical Environment consists of an [Environment Record](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) and **a possibly null reference to an outer Lexical Environment**.*

And each `function` is defined as having an [internal `[[Scope]]` property](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) (ref: Table 9), which references one such environment.

```
Function.[[Scope]] ->
  LexicalEnvironment.Outer ->
    LexicalEnvironment
    # etc.
```

The `.Outer` property in this is just a guess, but however the engine refers to the outer environment, its value is that of the current context's environment -- the `[[Scope]]` of the surrounding `function` or of the *program* itself.

When a `function` is called and references a variable, the engine can walk through the "*scope chain*" of environments and their records until it either finds the name being referenced or runs out of environments and throws a `ReferenceError`.

---

> Also, is there a way to inspect an Activation Object (much like how `__proto__` can be inspected)?

It's not currently possible within the language itself. Internal properties can't be accessed directly within JavaScript and the `[[Scope]]` property doesn't have anything to expose it like the `[[Prototype]]` property has `Object.getPrototypeOf()` or `__proto__`.

But, as Bergi mentioned, JavaScript debuggers may allow you to inspect the scope chain. For example, [under "Scope Variables" in Chrome's Web Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/):

> [image: "Scope Variables" in Chrome Web Tools]
> <sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging/callstack-region.jpg))</sub>

> While a script is paused, you can see the current call stack and in-scope variables in the right-hand side bar.

Comment: Chrome Console shows the scope objects of closures, also you can always inspect the scope chain in every debugger.